# Karate: Facing OAuth token issues after upgrading from 1.2.0 to 1.3.0

Tags: karate

My scenarios were working fine until version 1.2.0. Since I wanted to use @setup for data driven testing I bumped the version to 1.3.0. After that I started getting the following error while fetching OAuth token. Can someone please help.

```
    Given url 'https://oauth2***'
#    And retry until responseStatus == 200
    And header Content-Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    And form field grant_type = "client_credentials"
    And form field client_id = clientId
    And form field client_secret = clientSecret
    When method POST
    Then status 200
```

```
{"error_description":"Malformed client ID or secret in payload","error":"invalid_client"}
```

Comment: sorry it is impossible to help with this level of info. `@setup` is a breaking change. if you can't read the docs and figure it out, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: It's not related to @setup, the previous scenarios also stooped working

Comment: okay, so it may be a bug. follow the process please else no one can help. note that we spend months on RC versions asking for feedback, and many teams try those releases and avoid these surprises